# How to prevent iOS from resizing your UIViewController's view after return from background

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a `UIViewController` that displays a form with several text fields. In order to prevent the text fields from getting blocked by the keyboard, I resize the controller's view when the keyboard appears and disappears.

However, when the keyboard is up, the user presses the home button, and then returns to the app, the controller's view will be resized again to the size it was before the keyboard was up and the keyboard will still be showing.

What's causing my controller's view to be resized on return from background, and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Dismiss the keyboard
when the view is no longer required would be one way.  `ViewDidDisappear` or `dealloc` methods for instance

Comment: @JSA986 yes that would be one way. but if they keyboard is up and the user is expecting it to be up when they return, then that would be annoying. a solution that doesn't affect the user experience is what i'm looking for

Comment: Close keyboard when app goes in background. Can using TPKeyboard library solve your problem  ?, as you said some textfields gets blocked when keyboard is up.

Comment: @shoe, ok so set a flag when app goes into background and keyboard is shown and present the keyboard again if flag = true when user returns in `viewDidAppear`

Comment: @JSA986 i'm looking into that, but i'd still like to know why this is occurring in the first place

Comment: @JSA986 has a partial answer. In `viewDIdDisappear` you can also set a flag on the keyboard state so that in `viewWillAppear` you can bring the keyboard back up if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to nest a UIView，for example

```
_backgroundView = [UIView new];
_backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
_backgroundView.frame = CGRectZero;
[self.view addSubview:_backgroundView];
[_backgroundView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.left.right.top.mas_equalTo(self.view);
    make.height.mas_equalTo(self.view.mas_height);
}];
```

then you need add your custom UIView to this backgroundView.

as you said，UIViewController's view will be resized after return from background. so you can nest a UIView of the same size as self.view，and add your custom UIView to this UIView.

In order to prevent the text fields from getting blocked by the keyboard, you can resize this backgroundView when the keyboard appears and disappears. and this time when you click the home button to enter the background or return from background，self.view won't be resized and backgroundView won't be resized too.

Although it is a bit of a hassle, this will solve your problem and will not affect the user experience anymore. And if you have a better solution, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are setting the frame and not using autolayout.  When the view reappears viewDidLayoutSubviews gets called and your frame gets recalculated obliterating your previous change.  You can either:

1) Move your frame to viewDidLayoutSubviews and change its size only if the keyboard is showing.
2) Use autolayout and simply pull up your bottom constraint .constant by an amount equal to your keyboard height.

In both cases you should call layoutIfNeeded to trigger autolayout/viewDidLayoutSubviews when the keyboard appears/disappears.  This behavior is a good example of why you should not manipulate your frames outside of viewDidLayoutSubviews except for transitory animations.